# Multiple column update using 'SET' when none of the tables have primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables as below.

**Tabel A:**

```
    ResultID     | ImportDate | Comment1
    ----------------------------------------------
    101          | 25-09-2019 | One in Table A
    ----------------------------------------------
    101          | 25-09-2019 | One copy in Table A
    -----------------------------------------------
    102          | 25-09-2019 | Two in Table A
    -----------------------------------------------
    103          | 25-09-2019 | Three in Table A
    -----------------------------------------------
```

**Table B:**

```
    ResultID     | ImportDate | Comment2
    ------------------------------------------
    101          | 26-09-2019 | One in Table B
    ------------------------------------------
    101          | 26-09-2019 | One copy in Table B
    ------------------------------------------
    104          | 26-09-2019 | four in Table B
    -------------------------------------------
```

So the output should look like

**Table A:**

```
ResultID     | ImportDate | Comment1
---------------------------------------------
101          | 26-09-2019 | One in Table B
---------------------------------------------
101          | 26-09-2019 | One copy in Table B
--------------------------------------------
102          | 25-09-2019 | Two in Table A
--------------------------------------------
103          | 25-09-2019 | Three in Table A
---------------------------------------------
104          | 26-09-2019 | four in Table B
    -------------------------------------------
```

**Question:** 
I want to get resulting Table A as mentioned above if `ResultID` is matched between Table A and Table B, I want to update all column in Table A from Table B for that `ResultID`. If `ResultID` from Table B is not present in Table A, insert it to Table A.

**Note:** `ResultId` is not a primary key in both tables.

**What I have tried in MySQL:**
If `ResultId` is primary key, below solution works but I want to find solution when `ResultID` is not primary key.

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ResultID, ImportDate, Comment1)
SELECT ResultID, ImportDate, Comment2 FROM TableB
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
  ImportDate = VALUES(ImportDate),
  Comment1 = VALUES(Comment1);
```

For my real scenarios- I have 40 columns and 50,000 rows.

Could you please provide me any hint or solution? Thank you.

Comment: Are there other data values in the table? Otherwise, how do you decide which row from `TableB` should overwrite a given row in `TableA`?

Comment: @Nick There are other data values in the table too but I want to decide based on ResultId. If ResultId from Table B matches with ResultId in Table A, replace all column for that ResultId in Table A . If not, add row with ResultId from Table B to Table A

Comment: I understand. But you have two values for `ResultId = 101` in each of `TableA` and `TableB`, so how do you know which value to overwrite with? is there perhaps an auto_increment `id` field which can be used to order the data?

Comment: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table, which renders the question off topic for any kind of RDBMS

Comment: If I understand correctly, all you need to do is `DELETE` all the rows for a `ResultId` from Table1, if that `ResultId` exists in the Table2. And afterwards, you want to copy all the rows from Table2 to Table1 for that `ResultId`. This cannot be done in a single query, and will require two separate queries in a Transaction. From this comment, you should be able to figure out, what are those two steps.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58135630/multiple-column-update-between-two-table-with-set-in-mysql-and-with-no-primary?noredirect=1#comment102663313_58135630

If you can please check this just a bit update to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can perform like this.

```
SELECT CONCAT( "INSERT INTO ..... " )
FROM ....
```

Parsing your way in to generate SQL queries if the record did not exist from those tables :)  Quick and dirty.