# Multiple column update between two table with 'SET' in MySQL and with no primary key but identical entries

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have two tables as below.

Tabel A:

```
    ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment1
    -------------------------------------
    101          | 25-09-2019 | One
    101          | 25-09-2019 | Two
    103          | 25-09-2019 | Three
    103          | 25-09-2019 | Four
    ----------------------------------------
```

Table B:

```
    ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment2
    -------------------------------------
    101          | 26-09-2019 | new one
    101          | 26-09-2019 | new two
    104          | 26-09-2019 | new three
    104          | 26-09-2019 | new four
    --------------------------------------
```

So the output should look like

Table A:

```
ResultID(PK) | ImportDate | Comment1
-------------------------------------
101          | 26-09-2019 | new one
101          | 26-09-2019 | new two
103          | 25-09-2019 | Three
103          | 25-09-2019 | four
104          | 26-09-2019 | new three
104          | 26-09-2019 | new four
--------------------------------------
```

Question: I want to get resulting Table A as mentioned above if ResultID is matched between Table A and Table B, I want to update all column in Table A from Table B for that ResultID. If ResultID from Table B is not present in Table A, insert it to Table A. And the is no primary key for it. And entries would be unique like 2 entries for specific ResultID.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I think you're better off taking all the values in B and adding the missing ones from A, rather than trying to update with an ambiguous key

Comment: I have tried to remove the Result ID by using the following code:
"DELETE TableA
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ResultID = TableB.ResultID" 
Doing so will remove the common entries. Now the only thing is how would I be able to insert it from table B to A.

Comment: @nick if you can also please suggest on it wold be really helpful.

Comment: ResultID values do not conform to primary key.